# How to add packages to the micro and mini suse base images

Tags: containers, linux, dockerfile, images

I want to install tar and zstd packages to the base image of **registry.suse.com/bci/bci-minimal:15.5** and **registry.suse.com/bci/bci-micro:15.5** (taken from https://registry.suse.com/) but none of the images have zypper install , is there any other way i can install packages to this base images?